# Is it possible to make characters who are neurotic, who have low agreableness, low conscientiousness, low extraversion likeable?

Tags: creative-writing, characters, character-development

Is it possible to make characters who are neurotic, who have low agreeableness, low conscientiousness, low extraversion likeable?

I thought the only way to do this is to find something that the reader can relate to or find endearing, but for instance having a good sense of humour or having a soft spot for animals wouldn't work, because it would be inconsistent with their character. I don't think there's a lot of things these types of character share with the general public.

Comment: why do you want your characters to have those characteristics? What's the point? And, given you intend to have such a character, why do you want the reader to like them? I like almost no-one in either season of White Lotus but the stories are nonetheless compelling. Expand your question somewhat to show what problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: Some people can get attached to others quite easily in a way that says to me "getting attached to someone for no reason". It happens to me all the time, but I say that yes, that person can be likeable.

Comment: Your criteria described Homer Simpson if he was an introvert.